# Give input to a command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, arguments, user-input

I am trying to write a bash script with a command **gpg --full-generate-key**. After entering the command in the terminal it asks for input as shown in the below screenshot. So i want to use this command in the bash scripting by giving all the inputs before from a file.I have tried giving normal arguments to a sh file but it is not taking it. Any idea on how to give the input from file??[THis is what the command asks when entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSIX1.png)

[I am trying to write a bash script by giving input here but its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcATk.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `gpg` to see if it has command line options for those selections?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: My question is not just related to gpg. If there is any cmd which asks for input after entering the command how can we use those commands in a script file. I have tried giving arguments to script file itself as shown in screenshot but when the script is run and cmd inside is excuted it is asking for input again even wen i gave arguments. I even tried using "read" and giving input $1(argument )to read keyword in bash. it also didnt work

Answer (score 0):

As per the man page for gpg:

https://gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html

You can pass the options via a file with the --options parameter.